# How do I check if a std::string, containing utf8 text, starts with an uppercase letter in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm a complete novice as a Windows programmer and find it very hard to read Microsoft's documentation with all their weird custom types.

As far as I can tell, I need to use [`IsCharUpper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647485(v=vs.85).aspx), but I can't find any documentation that tells me how to use a `std::string` (containing utf8 text) and get a `TCHAR` representing the first character of the `std::string`.

The `std::string` is utf8 and standardising on something else is not an option. Only supporting *some* scripts is not an option either.

Comment: Neither the standard C++ library nor the Windows API is really good at handling UTF-8. I recommend you find some library to help you with all your Unicode problems. A good library should have functions to check if a character is upper-case or not.

Comment: `std::string` is a perfectly viable way to store utf8. Adding stuff like ICU is not a viable solution as we're pretty restrained memory wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCHAR is an alias in the Windows API and will represent a CHAR or a WCHAR depending on whether you have built your application for Unicode or not.

`MultiByteToWideChar` is the API you are looking for, it will take your utf8 input string and will fill in a WCHAR array. If your application is built for Unicode you will be able to pass WCHARs directly to `IsCharUpper`. If not, you can call `IsCharUpperW` which will take a `WCHAR` regardless of build configuration.

Something like this:

```
WCHAR out[2]={0};
int written = MultiByteToWideChar( 
  CP_UTF8, // Your input string is UTF8.
  0, // no flags apply
  your_string.c_str(), // the std::string you want to test
  your_string.length(), // can't pass 1 as the characters are variable size
  out, // Put the character here.
  1 // we want 1 character converted.
);
bool isUpper = false;
if(written == 1)
  isUpper = IsCharUpper(out[0]);
```

It is my recollection that this function doesn't need to write out a zero terminator  when given an exact number of characters to write so this should work.

Comment: Note that the conversion will fail for a non-BMP character such as mathematical script capital "" (U+1D49C), which would need two elements (a surrogate pair). But `IsCharUpperW` and [`GetStringTypeW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318119) don't support classifying non-BMP characters anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>


bool isUpper(const std::string& utf8Str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return IsUpperCase(myconv.from_bytes(utf8Str)[0]);
}
```

Comment: `IsUpperCase` is this a windows function?

Comment: @KilzoneKid yes, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647465(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I cannot seem to find it ;(

Comment: No it's not a Windows function or macro, or a C/C++ runtime function. It looks like `IsCharUpperW` was intended here?

Comment: It's interesting that the VC++ runtime doesn't call `MultiByteToWideChar` for this conversion, which means it has an internal implementation that may work more efficiently in this case.